# how can I retrieve a certain number of items from a list in the Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase Realtime Database I have structured the list of users as follows:

```
Users
 |
 | - 1@gmail.com
 |
 | - 2@gmail.com
 |
 | - 3@gmail.com
 |
 | - 4@gmail.com
 |
 | - 5@gmail.com
```

Using the Get () method, the whole list is returned to me, how can I retrieve only the first 3 users?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limitToFirst()` and provide it with the specific number you want:

```
void retrieveUsers() async {
    final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Users");
    DataSnapshot userSnapshot = await dbRef.limitToFirst(3).get();
}
```